# Change Field to Checkbox inside GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to change fields to a Checkbox inside a GridView.

I currently create Grid Columns Dynamically based on a query and some of the columns I want to change to a checkbox so it can be checked/unchecked by the user. I know I cant do this via .aspx page using  but I am trying to stay away from statically creating the fields.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of GridView's `RowDataBound` Event. Thus you can add any control to your GridView.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chk1 = new CheckBox();
                chk1.ID = "chkbox1";
                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(chk1);
            }
        }
```

**Edit for Comment:**

Once you passed the values from database to gridview (out of scope for this question), You can access the values using `e.Row.Cells[i].Text` where "i" is the row.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
           if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();
                txt1.Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
                e.Row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(txt1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks posting... I just have a question how do you now change a field thats already been bounded?

Comment: Hi , i coudn't get you. Did u try the example ?

Comment: Yeah it created an additional column as a checkbox. What I want is to take an existing column and convert it to a checkbox. Currently what I have is when I bind the data with the table my fields from database are bits so the GridView shows checkboxes that are generated by grid but I cannot access them because they are read only.